# Javascript Counting String with White Space

Tags: jquery, string, whitespace

So I need to count the length of a string lively, I mean like twitter, when you type, there is a counter which decreases as more character exist.

The problem is, when you type " " (whitespace), the counter start to count wrong, and be like that until another character exist.

Here's the code:

```
$(".tweet-content").bind("keydown", function(){
    var tweetlength = $(".tweet-content").html().length;
    $(".char-count").html(126-tweetlength);
});
```

When I enter `asdf` for example, it shows `122` (correct), but when I enter `asdf` (with a whitespace), it shows `116` (wrong). But when I enter `asdf a` (inserting 'a' after the whitespace), it shows `120` (correct).

So what's wrong with the whitespace?

Comment: Use `text()` instead of `html()` - assuming you aren't allowing people to enter HTML (which you really shouldn't be)

Comment: .tweet-content is a textarea or textfield?

Comment: That's just it? Oh well, haha, thank you very much, I've been searching all day just for this....

Comment: The space is `&nbsp;` in html. I think, this is the problem as @RoryMcCrossan mentioned.

Comment: @Dau it's a contenteditable element...

Comment: @lolka_bolka now I feel stupid haha, that's right by the way, I wasn't figure that out until you said that. thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$(".tweet-content").bind("keyup", function(){
    var tweetlength = $(".tweet-content").val().length;
    $(".char-count").html(126-tweetlength);
});
```

Use `keyup` event instead of `keydown` to get the last character in count too and use the `val()` function instead of 'html()'.

Answer (score 0):

Please user bellow code

```js
$(".tweet-content").bind("keydown", function(){
    var tweetlength = $(".tweet-content").html().replace(" ", "").length;
    $(".char-count").html(126-tweetlength);
});
```